# Regular Expression: Match the 5th to 12th character of a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I want to match the 5th to 12th character of a string using regular expressions.

String to match: '01010101' (8 characters)

Match only if the above string in present in the 5th to 12th position of an input string

For Eg:

- If the input string is AB127474737473727, this should not match.
- **If the input string is AB1201010101, this should match.**
- Input string - AB120101010, this should not match
- Input string - AB96, this should not match
- Input string - AK141001010101, this should not match
- **Input string - PG23010101012345, this should match**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```regex
^.{4}01010101
```

`^` asserts the start of a line

`.{4}` matches any 4 characters

`01010101` matches the next characters literally

Comment: "any character 4 times" might read less confusingly as "any 4 characters". Somebody not familiar with RegEx might think that it will only match, say "1111" or "aaaa", etc.